# Laravel 5 where to place and how to access image inside css

Tags: css, laravel-5

In Laravel 5, in what directory should I store images (for backgrounds) and how to access it inside a CSS file. My CSS file is on `public/css` directory. I've tried to place the image in `public/images` and `public/assets/images` but didn't work and even I couldn't access the image directly from web browser.

Answer (score 9):

In CSS you can access images, when they are in public/images, like

```
../images/imgename.jpg
```

In the blade template, you can use something like

"{{ asset('images/imagename.jpg') }}"

Comment: But inside a CSS file, this `{{ asset() }}` does not work at all. Any ideas on how to work around inside a CSS file or `<style></style>` ?

Comment: @Pathros You need to use the full path, or relevant path e.g ../images/imgename.jpg , If the image is in public/images folder.

Answer (score 1):

`public` is fine. You should access them in your css file via, e.g., `/images/xy.jpg` or `/assets/images/xy.jpg`. The / at the beginning makes sense to refer to the root directory.

If this does not work, please provide paths of images, css and an example css file that does not work with the images.

Answer (score 1):

All files inside of `public/` are accessible via web browser, just put the images or css there. Example:

```
public/images/foo.png
public/css/style.css
```

Normally in this structure is only needed to do `background: url('../images/foo.png')`.

However, some people has problems using absolute path like `background: url('/images/foo.png')`, why? because the laravel installation is made under `htdocs/` or `public_html/` having the following structure:

```
/home/user/public_html/laravel/public/
```

If the above structure is used by you, you need `background: url('/laravel/images/foo.png')`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use :  url(http://localhost:8000/imgs/image_name.extension) as follow my exemple : http://localhost:8000/img/spacer.png but pay atention do it in the dev enviroment in deploy change localhost:8000 for your domain name

Comment: Post your example here, don't just provide a link. (Links can become broken).

Comment: Those "links" are not real links. They're just an example (isn't the "localhost" part a hint that they're not actual Internet links?). Anyway, I don't think it's a good idea to absolutely reference the local environment and then having to change all links when moving to production.

Comment: But isn't there a more automatic way such as using `{{ asset('') }}` to make it painless, whenever you go on production?

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to use a tilde (~) instead of dots:

So the full line in the CSS became:

```
background: url('~/storage/images/DownArrow.png') no-repeat right #fff;
```

The storage folder being in the public folder.

With Laravel 5.7 I had been running 'npm run dev' and getting:
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './storage/images/DownArrow.png' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\websitename\resources\sass'

Thanks to 'mlachance' in another forum for the tip. He also says 'This is not well documented in the Vue CLI chapter on static assets.'